# How to change the font size of the text in textbox in python pptx

Tags: python, python-pptx

I want to change the font size of the test in textbox
I tried like...........

```
import os

from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.util import Inches, Pt
prs = Presentation()
blank_slide_layout = prs.slide_layouts[6]
slide = prs.slides.add_slide(blank_slide_layout)
shapes = slide.shapes
left = top = width = height = Inches(1)
txBox = slide.shapes.add_textbox(left, top, width, height)
tf = txBox.text_frame
tf.text = "Hello World"


prs.save('test.pptx')
os.startfile('test.pptx')
```

It is creating the ppt with Hello world text but I am not able to change the font size.
Second way I tried is like..

```
import os

from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.util import Inches, Pt
prs = Presentation()
blank_slide_layout = prs.slide_layouts[6]
slide = prs.slides.add_slide(blank_slide_layout)
shapes = slide.shapes
left = top = width = height = Inches(1)
txBox = slide.shapes.add_textbox(left, top, width, height)
tf = txBox.text_frame


p = tf.add_paragraph()
p.text = "Hello World"

p.font.size = Pt(40)
prs.save('test.pptx')
os.startfile('test.pptx')
```

But in this extra line is created at starting of text box and I don't want that line.

So is there any solution using first approach to change the font size  or using the second approach not to have extra line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. Here you can find more info about text formating in pptx-python https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/text.html

```
import os

from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.util import Inches, Pt
prs = Presentation()
blank_slide_layout = prs.slide_layouts[6]
slide = prs.slides.add_slide(blank_slide_layout)
shapes = slide.shapes
left = top = width = height = Inches(1)
txBox = slide.shapes.add_textbox(left, top, width, height)
tf = txBox.text_frame

p = tf.paragraphs[0]
run = p.add_run()
run.text = "Hello World"

font = run.font
font.name = 'Calibri'
font.size = Pt(64)

prs.save('test.pptx')
os.startfile('test.pptx')
```